# Generic exit function for iTerm2

Tags: command-line, bash, iterm, zsh

I've recently begun to use iTerm2 instead of the macOS Terminal application and I'm really happy with it. I'm very used to use to `exit` command to close the *instance* that currently has focus. With instance I mean one of the following: Tab, Window or Split Panel.

How can I write a function exit that closes the instance that is currently running? The following workaround works for windows but neither for tabs nor for split panels:

```
function exit {
    osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm2" to close first window'
}
```

The solution should work with either `zsh` or `bash`.

Comment: `exit` is a shell builtin (command).  Having a function with the same name is not a good idea.

Comment: This issue is not very clear.  When I have multiple instances of iTerm, typing exit only closes that instance (just tested to verify).

Comment: @Allan sorry for the confusion: *With instance I mean one of the following: Tab, Window or Split Panel.* That said I mean the following: If I have an iTerm2 Window containing of two tabs, I want to close the focused one by typing ``exit``. If this first tab is closed, ``exit`` closes the whole window (this is the part is already working).

Comment: *If this first tab is closed, exit closes the whole window*.  This is the part that's confusing.  If your first tab is closed, you no longer have an iTerm2 window consisting of two tabs.  You have a window consisting of *one* tab.  The exit is closing the only thing left.

Comment: @Allan Again sorry for the confusion. That is exactly what I would like to achieve since it mimics the default behaviour of any Linux terminal I am aware of.

Comment: Ok...so the way that I am reading this is you want the *exit* function to operate differently when there is > 1 window/tab/pane.  I don't see this as possible.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks so far. It *does* work using the Terminal app.

Comment: I think there's a confusion between exiting a session and closing a window.  I'm willing to be that in Terminal, when you type `exit`, it closes the *session* but leaves the window/tab/pane open.   Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section [Scripting](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html) of the [iTerm2 documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation.html) helped me fixing my problem.

In `.zshrc` I defined the following function:

```
function exit {
    osascript ~/.zsh/.function_exit.as
}
```

With `~/.zsh/.function_exit.as` as

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    tell current window to close current session
end tell
```

Additionally I set the following option in the iTerm2 settings:

[image]

[image]

Using all the above things together I achieve the following behaviour:

[image]

Since this does not depend on the Shell used everything should work perfectly using `bash` (and the corresponding dot-file).

Comment: This is a good solution with the exception of the function name.  `exit` is a [builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) and creating a function with a reserved name could cause adverse results.

Answer (score 5):

In Terminal, the default setting for handling closed sessions is to leave the window open.

In Preferences > Profiles:

[image]

In iTerm2, the default is to close the window

[image]

If you disable that option in iTerm2, it should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in your .profile you could add

alias killiTerm2='killall iTerm2'

the from the terminal, you would just call killiTerm2, and it would kill every running instance of iTerm2

Comment: This does in no way solve my problem since I don't want to close the whole application.